# Find magic numbers for bitboards

Tags: engines, software, programming, bitboard

I am writing a C++ chess [engine](https://github.com/RomainGoussault/Deepov) and I am looking for magic numbers for [Little-Endian Rank-File Mapping](https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Square+Mapping+Considerations#LittleEndianRankFileMapping) bitboards to generate moves for sliding pieces.

The rival chess [website](http://www.rivalchess.com/magic-bitboards/) gives magic numbers but not for the same board mapping.

The chess programming wiki gives [some of the best magic numbers so far](https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Best+Magics+so+far) but is not exhaustive.

At the end I am looking for four things:

- occupancy mask for each square
- magic number for each square
- magic shifts for each square
- moves database array for each square

So I can use the following [code](http://www.rivalchess.com/magic-bitboards/) to find the moves of the Rook on C3 (for instance):

```
bbBlockers = bbAllPieces & occupancyMaskRook[C3]

databaseIndex = (int)((bbBlockers * magicNumberRook[C3]) >> rookMagicShifts[C3])

bbMoveSquares = magicMovesRook[C3][databaseIndex] & ~bbFriendlyPieces
```

Comment: I believe this question will be better suited and answered at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ or http://stackoverflow.com/ .

Comment: Not really. This is still answerable here. BTW, programmers focus more on high-level abstraction. stackoverflow.com would have been better.

Comment: @PeteBecker You are right, I changed it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a very well known problem in chess programming. You should consider use the numbers generated by Pradyumna Kannan. Dr Kannan had kindly produced open-source the magic numbers. It is being used by Crafty and a few other chess engines including my own.

You can read more by google "Crafty magic number".

I've prepared a zipped file for you [here](http://smallchess.com/MagicMoves.zip). This is the same files being used in the SmallChess chess engine app. Please read the documentation. Basically, you'll need to call *Rmagic(square, occupancy)* for rooks and *Bmagic(square, occupancy)* for bishops. You can XOR those into a queen mask.

Comment: Thanks it works well. Can I freely use/modify this code in my chess engine?

Comment: There is no licence restriction. Use as you pleased. It wasn't me who did it, it was a contribution by Dr Kannan. Please accept my answer if it helps!

Comment: Hi, can you upload the file MagicMoves.zip to GoogleDrive? I can't download it at smallchess (I got some error). Thanks.

Comment: @123iamking The link is still working. I am not going to remove it.

Comment: @SmallChess - I don't ask about removing it, can you provide a mirror with Google Drive? Thanks.

Comment: @SmallChess Have you written the code in the zip file?

Comment: @AryanParekh It wasn't me who wrote it.

Comment: @SmallChess I need some help, regarding the magic bitboards, can you help me?

Comment: @AryanParekh Please post a new question. We can't provide individual level help here.

Comment: @SmallChess I understand! Its something that would be better suited in a chat room rather than a new question :)

Comment: @AryanParekh stackoverflow is a free service for all of us. I am not paid for offering expert level advice. I can’t help you one to one. Please start a new question so everybody can help.